# createReduxBoundAddListener is deprecated in react-navigation-redux-helpers@2.0.0! Please use reduxifyNavigator instead

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

I'm using react-navigation and redux for navigation between screens I'm getting an error instead.

> Invariant Violation: createReduxBoundAddListener is deprecated in
>   react-navigation-redux-helpers@2.0.0!  Please use reduxifyNavigator

I don't know how to fix it please help me out.

**App.js**

```
 import React from 'react';
 import { Provider } from "react-redux";
 import store from "./src/redux/store"      
 import { createReduxBoundAddListener } from "react- navigation-redux-helpers";
 import AppWithNavigationState from "./src/navigators/AppNavigator";

export default class App extends React.Component {
 render() {
  return (
   <Provider store={store}>

      //Here Im getting an error regarding creacteReduxBoundAddListener

     <AppWithNavigationState listener{createReduxBoundAddListener("root")}/>
   </Provider>
  );
 }
}
```

**AppNavigator.js file**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {PropTypes} from 'prop-types';
import {addNavigationHelpers,createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import LoggedOut from "../screens/LoggedOut";
import LogIn from "../screens/Login";
import ForgotPassword from "../screens/ForgotPassword";

// created screens using createStackNavigator

export const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  LoggedOut:{screen:LoggedOut},
  LogIn:{screen:LogIn},
  ForgotPassword:{screen:ForgotPassword},

});

const AppWithNavigationState = ({ dispatch,nav,listener}) =>{
  <AppNavigator navigation= 
  {addNavigationHelpers({dispatch,state:nav,addListener:listener})}/>
};

AppWithNavigationState.propTypes = {
  dispatch:PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  nav:PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state =>({
  nav:state.nav,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AppWithNavigationState);
```

**navigation.js**

```
import {AppNavigator} from "../../navigators/AppNavigator";


const firstAction = 
AppNavigator.router.getActionForPathAndParams("LoggedOut");  //decide which 
                                                             //screen will 
                                                             //load first

const initialNavState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(firstAction);

export const nav = (state=initialNavState, action)=>{
  let nextState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action,state);
  return nextState || state;
}
```

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/redux-integration.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this repo https://github.com/JaiDeves/AirBnB-React, I've updated the code with the newer version of react-navigation.